# Simple sqlite example in Cocoa Mac Desktop application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sqlite

Can anyone give me a simple sqlite example in Cocoa Mac? I want to use it in my Mac desktop application. I don't know how to use sqllite in a mac application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing strings to distant PHP file from Mac application. This is  how you can do it.

```
// form text fields and values
    NSArray *formfields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"password", @"confirm_password", nil];
    NSArray *formvalues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[nameField stringValue], [passwordField stringValue],[confirmField stringValue], nil];
    NSDictionary *textParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:formvalues forKeys:formfields];



// submit the form
[self doPostWithText:textParams];




- (void) doPostWithText:(NSDictionary *)textParams
{
    NSString *urlString = @"Your Remote PHP Url goes here!";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // add the text form fields
    for (id key in textParams) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[textParams objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a Cocoa wrapper for SQLite that's pretty commonly used.  See [fmdb.m](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb.m) for some examples.

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the file I linked!  It's just an interface to a relational database.  If you've got a more specific question, ask it.

Comment: @Nicholas-> ok, :) let me go through... again thanks for the help... :)

Comment: @Nicholas-> Can you give me a sample code for create a table & insert into table & select from it?

Comment: All three of those are in fmdb.m I linked to - just search for "create", "insert" and "select".

Comment: @Nicholas-> yea I have seen that! :) now working on it... :) thanks again... :)

Comment: @Nicholas-> we are working more on our project using sqlite ... We want to send two strings to a PHP file, Can you give us a sample code for that too???

Comment: @Joshua-> wow! Very funny! In that case there would be only a few Joshua's on Stack overflow! :) If I knew the answer then why would I asked! Yesterday while I asked, I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: @Nicholas-> sending strings to remote php file now working fine. Thanks again for the database help. we were trying for the past few days and were in vain! now it worked. thanks. :)

Comment: @Nicholas&Joshua-> I have posted an answer to this thread on how I used the code to pass two strings to distant PHP file from Mac application.